# Do I gain any experience from killing plants?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I can kill plants to get them out of my way but that usually results in me getting either poisoned or mana burned. Those negative effects usually mean I don't super want to kill the plants, because those effects are rather annoying, but if I do decide to kill the plants, do I get anything positive, like experience, from doing so?

Comment: I have not seen plants but you can easily test this yourself. Your experience bar is right below you portrait. If you would gain experience upon a hit it should have a faded out area for where your experience will be after your next hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I believe all plants have the attribute of "No Experience".  They are simply there to act as obstacles unless you are worshipping Earthmother, where they interact with her boons and piety effects.  You can also get a bit of piety from Glowing Guardian by getting hit with negative effects.

A good way to deal with plants that will poison or mana burn you is to wait until you are about to level up, and then kill as many of them as you can all at once.  Then level up to remove the negative effect.